# JSOUP parsing with table

Tags: android, parsing, jsoup

i have downloaded jsoup and copied into /libs but i have a big problem. I don't know parse this table and get value from  tags.
I have this table...

```
<table class="tabella-voli">
    <thead>
        <th>Compagnia</th>
        <th>N.</th>
        <th>Provenienza</th>
        <th>Schedulato</th>
        <th>Stimato</th>
        <th>Stato</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
                    <tr style="background-color: rgba(253, 253, 253, 0.8);">
            <td>RYANAIR</td>
            <td>05021</td>
            <td>Roma Ciampino</td>
            <td>09/04/2014 13:10</td>
            <td>09/04/2014 12:58</td>
            <td>
                                    <img src="/images/volo_green.gif"  alt="Atterrato" title="Atterrato"/><br /> Atterrato              </td>
        </tr>
                    <tr style="background-color: rgba(253, 253, 253, 0.8);">
            <td>RYANAIR</td>
            <td>01411</td>
            <td>Pisa</td>
            <td>09/04/2014 17:50</td>
            <td>09/04/2014 18:00</td>
            <td>
                                    <img src="/images/volo_green.gif"  alt="In orario" title="In orario"/><br /> In orario              </td>
        </tr>
                </tbody>
</table>
```

I want parse ONLY this:

```
<td>RYANAIR</td>
            <td>05021</td>
            <td>Roma Ciampino</td>
            <td>09/04/2014 13:10</td>
            <td>09/04/2014 12:58</td>
            <td>
```

and...

```
                <td>RYANAIR</td>
            <td>01411</td>
            <td>Pisa</td>
            <td>09/04/2014 17:50</td>
            <td>09/04/2014 18:00</td>
            <td>
```

and print into a textview.
This is my code:

```
                org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://mysite...").get();

            Element tabella = doc.getElementsByClass("tabella-voli").first();
            Elements tbody = doc.getElementsByTag("tbody");
            Elements element = tbody;
            System.out.println(element.text());
```

can you help me please? sorry for my english!
i am newbie :) :) 
Thank you guys!!!

Comment: For each `table.tabella-voli tr`, check the text contents of the first `td` for *RYANAIR*. If positive, extract the rest of the `tr`.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this is to select the tr elements first, then go ahead and select each child cell (td) under that td.   This would look like:

```
Elements tableRows = doc.select("table.tabella-voli > tbody > tr");
```

Then go a head and get each cell from the row, printing something like this:

```
for (Element tableRow : tableRows) {
     System.out.println("New Row:");
     Elements tableRowCells = tableRow.select("> td");
     for (Element tableRowCell : tableRowCells) {
          System.out.println(tableRowCell.ownText());
     }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
Element table = doc.select("table[class=tabella-voli]").first();

Iterator<Element> ite = table.select("td").iterator();

System.out.println("Value 1: " + ite.next().text());
System.out.println("Value 2: " + ite.next().text());
System.out.println("Value 3: " + ite.next().text());
System.out.println("Value 4: " + ite.next().text());
```